# What are the ways to share a buffer between two threads using C in Windows?

Tags: c, multithreading, winapi

think about scenario like i have created 2 threads using `createthread()` of win32 api. i am getting continues  data in one thread which is connected to one serial port and 2nd thread will perform operation on the data of thread 1. i stored the data in one buffer in thraed 1. but i want to use that buffer in thread 2 , so that i can continue my operation on data by using thraed 2 function. so how i can share the data between two threads.

Comment: Try adding 0xfffffff and 0xffffffff ... or even larger numbers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `printf` functions returns the number of elements written. In this case is the number of characters which is the sum of `x` (the first `%*c`) and `y` (the second).

Answer (score 1):

That's no addition. The function `add` simply return what `printf` returns, which returns the number of characters printed.

You *do* know that addition is done with the `+` operator?

Comment: It looks like a weird format string where the precision is selected from the parameter, so the number of chars printed happens to be X+Y

Comment: @Roddy Ah yes that correct. It's a... *weird* way of doing addition!